# Timeout async/await functions after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, node-oracledb

I created a function to get an Oracle connection using oracledb, but in a few cases, oracledb didn't throw an exception even if he didn't get the connection, apparently he's trying to connect infinitely.

```
const getConnection = async (): Promise<oracledb.Connection | undefined> => {
  let connection;

  try {
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
      user: process.env.DB_LOGIN,
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
      connectString: process.env.DB_STRING_CONNECTION,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  return connection;
};
```

I saw a few samples using Promise.racing with setTimeout but i couldn't put it in pratice, my tries always get an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning on console so i think it isn't the correct way.

Can anybody show me an example how to do that?

Comment: There's not much you can do if the library keeps retrying. Usually the library would provide a way to override that mechanism or limit it to a number of retries. Which library is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.race` should work fine if you implement it properly. Race the `getConnection` against a Promise that resolves (not rejects), and make sure to chain to a `.catch`.

```
const getConnection = (): Promise<oracledb.Connection | undefined> => {
    return Promise.race([
        oracledb.getConnection({
            user: process.env.DB_LOGIN,
            password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
            connectString: process.env.DB_STRING_CONNECTION,
        }),
        new Promise((resolve) => { setTimeout(resolve, 5000); })
    ])
        .catch((error) => {
            // this will only be entered into if getConnection rejects (and not if it times out)
            console.log(error);
        })
};
```

Comment: _"[Promise.race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) method returns a promise that fulfills or rejects as soon as one of the promises in an iterable fulfills **or rejects**..._" - and I wouldn't put the `.catch` handler inside the `getConnection` function. Instead allow the caller to catch the error and handle as needed, perhaps attempting a certain number of retries.

Comment: Thank you CertainPerformance, that's work just fine

Comment: The `*or rejects*` is why I put the `.catch` outside the `.race`. If the `getConnection` rejects, the `.catch` will be entered into, and the returned Promise will resolve then, to `undefined`. Yeah, having the caller of `getConnection` catch possible problems would usually be the way to go, but it doesn't sound like that's how OP wants to structure things, since he's getting unhandled rejections in his original code

Comment: fair points. thanks for the discussion :D

Comment: One thing Promise.race won't help is if the underlying network connection to the DB is hung waiting for a TCP timeout.  The solution to this was posted in another answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you can set a timeout on your `connectString`:

> With Oracle Client 19c, timeouts can be passed in Easy Connect strings, for example to timeout after 15 seconds: "mydbmachine.example.com/orclpdb1?connect_timeout=15"

http://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#dbcalltimeouts

Which means you could just as simply construct the string with the timeout:

```
connectString: process.env.DB_STRING_CONNECTION + '?connect_timeout=15',
```

Of course there are much better ways to handle the construction of your string.

You can use this connection string format to specify the timeout without 19c client:

```
(DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=15 ms)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=mymachine.example.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))(RETRY_COUNT=3)
```

(Also part of the documentation linked)

Comment: In my case, it isn't Oracle 19c, but thanks anyway MinusFour

Comment: @KauanPolydoro You can still use other connection string to set the timeout. [Here's how to use a full connector string](http://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#-1512-embedded-connect-descriptor-strings).

Answer (score 2):

CertainPerformance's answer is great, however I would suggest not entangling timeout logic with your function. These are generic things and should be implemented separately from your connection logic.

I think the approach below is good because the `timeout` is configurable by the caller, allowing them to decide how much time a task should wait.

```js
const sleep = ms =>
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))

const timeout = (p, ms) =>
  Promise.race([
    p,
    new Promise((_, r) => sleep(ms).then(_ => r(Error("timeout"))))
  ])
  
const fakeConnect = () =>
  sleep(2000).then(_ => "connected!")


// Example 1: 500 ms timeout
timeout(fakeConnect(), 500)
  .then(console.log, console.error)  // Error: timeout

  
// Example 2: 10 second timeout
timeout(fakeConnect(), 10000)        // connected!
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```